# Check table compatibility in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have some tables declared that represent remote databases.

I want to check that my table definitions match the remote databases I connect to.

I have the following function:

```
def verify_db_tables(conn, metadata):
    """checks that the tables declared in metadata are actually in the db"""
    for table in metadata.tables.values():
        check = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
        check.reflect(conn, table.schema, True, (table.name,))
        check = check.tables[table.key]
        for column in table.c:
            if column.name not in check.c:
                raise Exception("table %s does not contain column %s" %
                        (table.key, column.name))
            check_column = check.c[column.name]
            if check_column.type != column.type:
                raise Exception("column %s.%s is %s but expected %s" %
                        (table.key, column.name, check_column.type, column.type))
```

I specifically don't care if there are additional columns in tables, and don't care if there are additional tables.

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Exception: column dx.mail_data.message_id is INTEGER but expected INTEGER
```

How do I check that a column in the reflected table is of the same type as my definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite uses a class heiarchy so this will work nicely

```
    if not instance(check_column.type, column.type.__class__):
```

Comment: doh!  Thanks.  Obvious in hindsight.